# Why didn't back quotes in a shell script help me cd to a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script with the following code:

```
dir=sample
`mkdir $dir`
`cp /home/bhavya/workspace/UnetStack/logs/log-0.txt $dir/log.txt`
`cd $dir`
```

In the last line with the `cd` command in the back quotes, I was not able to `cd` into the corresponding directory. 
But once I removed the back quotes I was able to `cd`. 
What I was wondering is why didn't the `cd` work with the back quote?

Comment: Why do you think you need back quotes here ?

Comment: I think you're confused about [what backticks do](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-bash)... I don't think your script needs them at all.

Comment: @David that link helped thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you ran:

```
`mkdir $dir`
```

the shell first ran the command `mkdir $dir` in a subshell, capturing its (standard) output, and then ran the captured string as a command.  Fortunately, the output was empty, so the second step executed nothing.

When you then ran:

```
`cp /home/bhavya/workspace/UnetStack/logs/log-0.txt $dir/log.txt`
```

the copy was executed in a subshell, and the output was captured and executed.  Again, the output was empty, so the second phase of execution did nothing.

Then you ran:

```
`cd $dir`
```

Once more, the `cd` operation was run in a subshell, which exited after changing its own current working directory, but without affecting the parent shell (this is Unix, not a DOS `.bat` command file).  As before, the output of the `cd` command was captured, and executed, but the output was empty so there was nothing to execute.

Essentially, you don't use back-quotes as extensively as you are doing.

It would be sufficient to write:

```
dir=sample
mkdir $dir
cp /home/bhavya/workspace/UnetStack/logs/log-0.txt $dir/log.txt
cd $dir
...other activity in the new directory...
```

Note that if this is in a script, then the normal ways of executing a script would still leave the parent shell in the original directory.  There are ways to make it affect the original shell — find out about the `.` command (or, in `bash`, the `source` command; that's easier to search for).

You normally use back quotes (or, better, the `$(...)` notation) to capture data.  For example:

```
gcc_lib_dir=$(dirname $(dirname $(which gcc)))/lib
```

The innermost command is `which gcc`; it might yield `/usr/gcc/v4.7.1/bin/gcc`; the inner `dirname` then yields `/usr/gcc/v4.7.1/bin`; the outer dirname yields `/usr/gcc/v4.7.1`; the appended `/lib` gives

```
gcc_lib_dir=/usr/gcc/v4.7.1/lib
```

That also shows why `$(...)` is superior to the back-quote notation:

```
gcc_lib_dir=`dirname \`dirname \\\`which gcc\\\`\``/lib
```

That's harder to get right, and harder to type!

Comment: helped clarify why and where I would require to use backticks in the script

Comment: +1. I can only add: quote your `$dir` variable (e.g., `"$dir"`). This way, "strange" characters like spaces and the like won't cause any new problems in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Backquotes run the commands within in a subshell. The subshell changed directory, but there is no way to propagate this back up to the script's shell.